# Training and classifier computer vision

Tags: image, vision

What is the meaning of training a data(set of images) in computer vision and how it is done ?
what are classifiers?

Comment: Do you want us to provide you with a degree in Computer Science and Artificial Intelligence, or just a wiki link?

Comment: can you provide degree?

Answer (score 10):

In machine learning, you have some sort of learning algorithm. A learning algorithm takes some data, called the training set, and produces a model of the world from that. So suppose you had a computer vision learning algorithm that attempted to classify images into two categories: it's a picture of a face, or it's not a picture of face.

To keep things simple, just assume the learning algorithm is very stupid - you feed it pictures of faces marked "face" and pictures of things that don't have faces marked "not a face." Our dumb algorithm then just calculates the average light intensity of pictures marked "face" and produces a model that says "if the average intensity of a picture is closer to the average intensity of pictures I previously saw marked "face" than pictures I previously saw that were marked "not a face", then predict that the picture I'm being shown is a face."

The pictures you had to show it to calculate the average light intensity of images of faces as well as pictures marked "not a face" is the training set.

The training set is contrasted with the testing set. It's not very impressive for an algorithm to produce a model that tells you a picture is of a face if you've already shown it that picture before. So usually when you have data you "hold out" (or set aside) a small portion to evaluate how good the model actually is.

**The basic process of a machine learning task breaks down as follows:**

1. Obtain, prepare, and format data so that it can be used as input for a model.
2. Through random choice, set aside some portion of the data to be designated as the "training set" and the other as the "testing set." Usually like 10% or so is set aside for testing.
3. Apply the learning algorithm to the training set.
4. The output of a learning algorithm is a model which accepts input and produces some output given that input. In a computer vision context, the input is almost always going to be a picture, but the output could be a classification, perhaps a 3-D map, maybe it finds certain things in the picture; it depends on what you're trying to do.
5. Determine the accuracy of the model by feeding it the data it's never seen before (i.e. the testing set) and compare the output of the model with what you know the output should be.

Answer (score 1):

You use training data to build a classifier.

How it is done exactly? It varies. In a nutshell you need some sort of distance measure, a simple rule, to compare your samples against each other. You also need a rule to make decisions, that decides whether this object belongs to class A or class B, let's say.

The trick is to find such distance measure that is very simple but varies a lot across images of different classes. For making decisions you can rely on information theory and select any of the available techniques, such as: svm, rf.

Comment: One way to look at it